# Custom layout for RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

Is there any way I can change the layout for a RadioButton and still have the RadioGroup recognise it?

what I need is that the layout will include a couple of EditText fields so that when the user selected that button those fields become active.
I know I can built a custom part based on LinearLayout and set my own layout using: 
(LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, true)
but can't figure out how to do the same thing with a radio button.

I have tried the option of having the extra fields outside the RadioGroup and lining them up with the button but it simply doesn't work. 
It seems to be too device-dependant.

This is what the original layout looked like:

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_hours_prompt"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_selector_hours_prompt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/time_selector_first_radio"
    >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_first_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_second_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_third_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_hours_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        />

</RadioGroup>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_all_day_prompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_radio_group"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_selector_hours_prompt"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
    android:text="@string/time_all_day"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_before_noon_prompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_radio_group"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_selector_all_day_prompt"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dip"
    android:text="@string/time_before_noon"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_after_noon_prompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_radio_group"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_selector_before_noon_prompt"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dip"
    android:text="@string/time_after_noon"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_starting_time_prompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/time_selector_starting_date_prompt"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_selector_after_noon_prompt"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:text="@string/advanced_time_selector_dialog_starting_time_prompt"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_starting_time"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/time_selector_starting_date"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/time_selector_starting_time_prompt"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field_bg"
    android:inputType="datetime"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_ending_time_prompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/time_selector_ending_date_prompt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/time_selector_starting_time_prompt"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/time_selector_starting_time_prompt"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:text="@string/ending_date_prompt"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_ending_time"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/time_selector_ending_date"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/time_selector_ending_time_prompt"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field_bg"
    android:inputType="datetime"
    />
```

Note that the button doesn't have any text and it is added in a TextView so that we can have it on the left.
What was happening was that the text was "creeping up".

So, I changed it to look like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/time_selector_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_hours_prompt"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_selector_hours_prompt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/time_selector_first_radio"
    >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_all_day_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/time_all_day"
        android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_before_noon_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/time_before_noon"
        android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/time_selector_after_noon_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/time_after_noon"
        android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">   
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/time_selector_hours_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/advanced_time_selector_dialog_starting_time_prompt"
            android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dip"
            android:paddingLeft="-1dip"
            />  
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_hours_radio"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">            
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/time_selector_starting_time"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
                android:background="@drawable/text_field_bg"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/time_selector_hours_radio"
                android:inputType="datetime"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_selector_ending_time_prompt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                android:text="@string/ending_date_prompt"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/time_selector_hours_radio"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_starting_time"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/time_selector_ending_time"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/advanced_time_selector_edit_texts_width"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time_selector_ending_time_prompt"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/time_selector_hours_radio"
                android:background="@drawable/text_field_bg"
                android:inputType="datetime"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

It is still not perfect and, of course, it doesn't recognise it as a RadioGroup.

I wanted to go the direction of extending the RadioButton but have no idea how to change the layout there.

Comment: any sample code, with what you tried?

Comment: @donfede see additions

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a custom `RadioGroup` called `RadioGroupPlus` where it will traverse through it's children and find `RadioButton` regardless how deep the `RadioButton` is nested, it will then link all the `RadioButton` found together.

You can find the repo here: https://github.com/worker8/RadioGroupPlus

The `README` of the repo covers how to use it, and it actually works just like how you imagine it, for example:

```
<worker8.com.github.radiogroupplus.RadioGroupPlus
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_plus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout...>
       <ImageView...>
       <TextView...>
       <RadioButton...>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout...>
       <ImageView...>
       <TextView...>
       <RadioButton...>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout...>
       <ImageView...>
       <TextView...>
       <RadioButton...>
    </LinearLayout>
</worker8.com.github.radiogroupplus.RadioGroupPlus>
```

Will give you something like this:

[image]

In your case, since you already have the xml layout file, try to download `RadioGroupPlus` by following the [guide here](https://github.com/worker8/RadioGroupPlus#downloadinstall):

Add this to top level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Add this under dependencies:

```
compile 'com.github.worker8:RadioGroupPlus:v1.0.1'
```

Then in your xml, change `RadioGroup` to `worker8.com.github.radiogroupplus.RadioGroupPlus`. Now all your `RadioButton`s under `RadioGroupPlus` should all be linked together.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to create **a class that extends RadioGroup**, and override **addView** and **PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener**, to be able to use custom layouts for your radio button. By default, RadioGroup assumes that its children are radio buttons, see code below from the RadioGroup class:

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (child instanceof RadioButton) {
        final RadioButton button = (RadioButton) child;
        if (button.isChecked()) {
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = true;
            if (mCheckedId != -1) {
                setCheckedStateForView(mCheckedId, false);
            }
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = false;
            setCheckedId(button.getId());
        }
    }

    super.addView(child, index, params);
}

private class PassThroughHierarchyChangeListener implements
        ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener {
    private ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener mOnHierarchyChangeListener;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        if (parent == RadioGroup.this && child instanceof RadioButton) {
            int id = child.getId();
            // generates an id if it's missing
            if (id == View.NO_ID) {
                id = View.generateViewId();
                child.setId(id);
            }
            ((RadioButton) child).setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(
                    mChildOnCheckedChangeListener);
        }

        if (mOnHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
            mOnHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewAdded(parent, child);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
        if (parent == RadioGroup.this && child instanceof RadioButton) {
            ((RadioButton) child).setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(null);
        }

        if (mOnHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
            mOnHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewRemoved(parent, child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question may become decade-old, but I am dropping it to help others stuck in this situation.

I used `TextView` in place of `Radio Button` and **create a class to group them**, it may be old style but I found it the most elegant and flexible way for me.

XML for TextView layout:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
    <TextView... android:id="@+id/o1">
    <TextView... android:id="@+id/o2">
    <ImageView...>
    <TextView... android:id="@+id/o3">
    <TextView... android:id="@+id/o4">
</RelativeLayout>
```

ButtonGroup.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
...

public class ButtonGroup {
    ArrayList<TextView> mOptions;
    int cur=0;
    int colorOn = Color.BLUE;
    int colorOff = Color.GRAY;
    ButtonGroup(ArrayList<TextView> options) {
        mOptions = options;
    }

    public void turnOn(int i){
        if(i!=cur){
            TextView pre = mOptions.get(cur);
            pre.setTextColor(colorOff);
            cur=i;
        }

        TextView next = mOptions.get(i);
        next.setTextColor(colorOn);
    }
}
```

onCreate method of Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int current = 0;
    ArrayList<TextView> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
    optionList.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.o1));
    optionList.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.o2));
    optionList.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.o3));
    optionList.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.o4));
    ButtonGroup options = new ButtonGroup(optionList);
    options.turnOn(current);
}
```

it will give something like

[image]