# Custom Android RadioButton

Tags: android, user-interface, view, radiobuttonlist

In Android I want a RadioButton that has two associated TextViews, not the one available by default.  So, each RadioButton would have a 'label' and short 'description'.  The reason I need two (not that you care) is that I want each field to have different styles.

Do I need to make a custom RadioButton to do this?  If so, I'm not sure on the approach. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515728/custom-layout-for-radiobutton) is the best lead I have so far, but I'm really surprised its not inflating a custom layout.

Comment: you can also add a textview with a radio button. So you will have two labels one for radio and other for the textview

Comment: You might look into using a single `TextView` with a `Span` value. If you use `Html.fromHtml()` you can use `<br>` to make multiple lines and `<b>` and `<font>` tags to format them. As in `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Label</b><br>Description"))`.