# is it possible to inflate a layout and set as a view for RadioButton - android

Tags: android, android-view, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have three `RadioButton`'s inside a `RadioGroup`

I removed the check inside the `RadioButton` by using `android:button="@null"`

Now I want to inflate a layout like this screen shot, inside the `RadioButton` with "Text A", "Small Title" is that possible?

[image]

I want it as `RadioButton` so when the "Text A" is clicked it should be showed in the top layout.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is NO. You can change the drawable, but not inflate a layout

Comment: @yashhy no u can't..@Der Golem is right.

Comment: is there any other way to do it? I need a radio button because to select one item at a time.

Comment: There's already similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515728/custom-layout-for-radiobutton